# Using Code-first Entity Framework to add new tables to large, existing database which is consumed by non-EF applications

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ddl

I'm writing a small application which requires ~6 new tables to be added to a large database (~100 tables). My application is not interested in any of the existing tables or DB structure, indeed it's likely my new tables will all be in a new schema.

Other people will be writing stored procedures to access my new tables so I can't see them being happy without a DDL to refer to. I'm new to EF but because these tables have a lot of fields it seems a good option to avoid manually creating the DDL.

What is the best option here? I'm wondering if I should use EF anyway but just as a way to spit out a DDL using annotations? I'm brand new to EF so please assume little knowledge if you start talking about migrations, etc!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, use migrations :)

Migrations saves a "state" table (__Migrations) on your db (with a copy of your model, but dont bother about it now). It uses it to compare your "current" application model with "database" implementation (it ignores any table not belonging to your code).

Once using migrations, you have some goodies:

1. You can get the SQL of your initial model
2. You get "scheme" upgrades when you add/delete/modify tables and its SQL.
3. You can also get the SQL to move from modification "x" to modification "y".

It is a bit frustrationg when you don't know it at first, but you learn how to use it on little time.

Recommendations:

- Keep your DAL on a separate pr
- Add migrations from the "Package" console

  Enable-Migrations -Project MyDALProjectName
- Inmmediatly add an initial migration

  Add-Migration Initial -Project MyDALProjectName"
- Get the script for fun (note the script parameter)

  Update-Database -Project MyDALProjectName -Script"

  Notice the insert  on __Migrations which is needed.
- Apply the initial migration "Update-Database -Project MyDALProjectName", which is the same as running the script against your database.

From here, always do as follows when you have changes in your model (your app will refuse to run until you do):

- Add-Migration MigrationNameWithDetailsOnWhatYoDid -Project MyDALProjectName
- Update-Database -Project MyDALProjectName
- To update production database: 
  Update-Database -Project MyDALProjectName -SourceMigration TheMigrationIWantToApplyFrom -TargetMigrations ToMigrationNameUssuallyLatestOne -Script

Some side notes:

- __Migrations table have a list of "modification" keys, right? You can check database's last applied migration here.
- "Migrations" folder on your project has a list of classes matched with the table. They have the c# code which generates the changes.
- You can reset migrations deleting both table and migration classes in the "Migrations" folder. Be carefull once in production.
- You can revert migrations, I only needed that when you facing problems...

Those are important tips which will help you move forward.

Check http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application